# Finding the time difference in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

So I have following data frame structure.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group':list('aaaabbbb'),
                   'value':[1,3,3,2,5,6,6,2],
                   'id':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
                   'datetime':pd.datetime('01/01/2011 01:00:00',
'01/01/2011 01:02:00',
'01/01/2011 01:05:00',
'01/01/2011 01:06:00',
'01/01/2011 03:00:00',
'01/01/2011 04:00:00',
'01/01/2011 05:00:00',
'01/01/2011 10:00:00')})
df
```

For each group and id, which let's say is a store and franchise, I want to find the difference between each datetime. Thus, I'd end up with the following output.

```
group   id   timediff
b       2    ...
b       3    ...
```

In my use case, I have tried something like this, but not getting the desired outcome.

```
df.loc[df.id.isin([2,3])].sort_values(['group','hour','datetime']).groupby('id')['datetime'].diff()
```

Expected Output:

Within each group, let's say the id represents each franchise.
I'm trying to find the difference in AVERAGE datetime between those where id is 2 or 3.

So....

```
group   id   timediff.avg
b       2    ...
b       3    ...
```

for store a, and franchise 2, the average time diff was ...

Comment: Can you give a more concrete expected output for this data please?

Comment: Is `df.set_index(['group', 'id']).groupby(level=[0, 1]).datetime.diff().dropna()` what you want?

Comment: Your output still isn't right... there's no `c` group in the input.

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you're looking for -

1. Query out relevant rows with the requisite `id`
2. Group on `group` and `id` columns
3. Find the groupies `diff` of the `datetime` column
4. Extract the total seconds component from the result and find its mean
5. Divide by 60 to get the result in hours

```
df.query("id in [2, 3]")\
  .set_index(['group', 'id'])\
  .groupby(level=[0, 1])\
  .datetime.diff()\
  .dt.total_seconds()\
  .dropna()\
  .mean(level=[0,1])\
  .div(60)

group  id
a      2       1.0
b      3     180.0
Name: datetime, dtype: float64
```